# How to convert JSONObject to .csv in GWT?

Tags: java, json, csv, gwt

I'm totally new to GWT, so sorry if this is a trivial question, but I can't find the answer. I'm having this already working function(s) where I can export as .xlsx one table. This is okay, it's exporting the file without any issues. This is using this 3rd party utility: https://github.com/stephenliberty/excel-builder.js/

My problem I want to save the file as .csv but I can't convert this gwt version of JSONObject (
com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject.JSONObject()) into csv and I can't find any usefull documentation about this excel-builder-js if this could also export in csv or not... How is this possible?

```
    ...
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("head", head);
            object.put("cols", columns);
            object.put("data", array);
            exportXlsxFromTable(JsonUtils.safeEval(object.toString()), GWT.getModuleName(), name);
    ...

    public static native void exportXlsxFromTable(JavaScriptObject originalData, String project, String name) /*-{
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,';
    $wnd
            .require(
                    [ project + '/excelbuilderjs/excel-builder', project + '/excelbuilderjs/Template/BasicReport' ],
                    function(EB, BR, downloader) {
                        var basicReport = new BR({
                            name : name
                        });
                        basicReport.setHeader([
                            {bold: false, text: name}, "", ""
                        ]);
                        var head = originalData['head'];
                        for (var i=0;i<head.length;i++) {
                            for (var j=0;j<head[i].length;j++) {
                                head[i][j].metadata = { type: 'string' };
                            }
                        }
                        basicReport.setData(head.concat(originalData['data']));
                        basicReport.setColumns(originalData['cols']);

                        var data = EB.createFile(basicReport.prepare());
                        //          window.location.href = uri + data;
                        $entry(@com.mycompany.gxt.framework.view.dom.DOMUtils::downloadFile(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)("myfile.xlsx", uri, data));

                    });
    }-*/;

public static native void downloadFile(String filename, String uri, String base64) /*-{
    var iframeDownloadFn = function(filename, uri, base64) {
        var values = {
            fn : 'b64d',
            fname : filename,
            fcont : uri + base64
        };
        try {
            $wnd.document.body.removeChild($wnd.downloadIframe);
        } catch (e) {
        }
        var iframe = $wnd.document.createElement("iframe");
        $wnd.document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        var iDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var form = iDoc.createElement("form");
        form
                .setAttribute("action",
                        @com.mycompany.gxt.framework.client.FrameworkClient::DOWNLOAD_URL);
        form.setAttribute("method", 'POST');
        form.setAttribute("style", 'display: none');
        for ( var property in values) {
            if (values.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                var value = values[property];
                if (value instanceof Array) {
                    for (var i = 0, l = value.length; i < l; i++) {
                        var el = iDoc.createElement("input");
                        el.setAttribute("type", 'hidden');
                        el.setAttribute("name", property);
                        el.setAttribute("value", value[i]);

                        form.appendChild(el);
                    }
                } else {
                    var el1 = iDoc.createElement("input");
                    el1.setAttribute("type", 'hidden');
                    el1.setAttribute("name", property);
                    el1.setAttribute("value", value);
                    form.appendChild(el1);
                }
            }
        }
        iDoc.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        $wnd.downloadIframe = iframe;
    }
    var clickLink = function(link, uri, base64) {
        var cancelled = true;

        try {
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                cancelled = !link.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else if (link.fireEvent) {
                cancelled = !link.fireEvent("onclick");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            cancelled = true;
        }

        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);

        if (cancelled) {
            iframeDownloadFn(filename, uri, base64);
        }
    }
    var link = $wnd.document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", uri + base64);
    link.setAttribute("name", filename);
    link.setAttribute("title", filename);
    link.setAttribute("download", filename);
    $wnd.document.body.appendChild(link);
    clickLink(link, uri, base64);
}-*/;
```

**EDIT.:**

Tried with the javasript suggestion from "Mon Mohon Singha", I'm here right now:

```
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("head", head);
object.put("cols", columns);
object.put("data", array);

exportCsvFromTable(object.toString(), GWT.getModuleName(), name);

public static native void exportCsvFromTable(String originalData, String project, String name) /*-{
var uri = 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;';

function convertToCSV(jsData){
     var json = jsData;
     var fields = Object.keys(json[0]);
     var replacer = function(key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value }
     var csv = json.map(function(row){
       return fields.map(function(fieldName){
         return JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)
       }).join(',')
     })
     csv.unshift(fields.join(',')) // add header column
     return csv.join('\r\n');
   }

var data = convertToCSV(originalData);
//     window.location.href = uri + data;
$entry(@com.mycompany.gxt.framework.view.dom.DOMUtils::downloadFile(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)("export.csv", uri, data));

}-*/;
```

but I'm getting this error, so I assume I'm not using the right type...

```
com.google.gwt.logging.client.LogConfiguration
SEVERE: Exception caught: Exception caught: (TypeError) : json_0_g$.map is not a function com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: (TypeError) : json_0_g$.map is not a function
 at Unknown.fillInStackTrace_0_g$(as-0.js@3:130944)
 at Unknown.Throwable_3_g$(as-0.js@8:130899)
 at Unknown.Exception_3_g$(as-0.js@18:131042)
 at Unknown.RuntimeException_3_g$(as-0.js@18:287158)
 at Unknown.UmbrellaException_3_g$(as-0.js@25:313985)
```

**EDIT2.:**

This is the logged out JavaScriptObject. Removed some of the "data" lines to be more clear:

```
Object
cols: Array(10)
0: {name: "ID", type: "string"}
1: {name: "NAME", type: "string"}
2: {name: "FIRST NAME", type: "string"}
3: {name: "BIRTHDAY", type: "string"}
4: {name: "BIRTH PLACE", type: "string"}
5: {name: "BIRTH COUNTRY", type: "string"}
6: {name: "NATIONALITY", type: "string"}
7: {name: "ORGANISATION", type: "string"}
8: {name: "FUNCTION", type: "string"}
9: {name: "PLACE", type: "string"}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
data: Array(100)
0: (10) [1470, "John", "Doe", "03.03.1988", "", "", "CANADA", "BPA", "", ""]
1: (10) [1469, "Test", "NAme", "25.03.1999", "CANADA", "CANADA", "CANADA", "test", "", "LA"]
2: (10) [1467, "Mike", "Test2", "06.05.2019", "Paris", "", "", "test", "ikol", "LA"]
3: (10) [1465, "Flanders", "Ned2", "23.12.1974", "Salt Lake City", "", "", "Orgatest", "BPA", ""]
4: (10) [1462, "Bro", "Jo", "03.07.2018", "abc", "USA", "USA", "MY COMPANY", "Catering", "A"]
5: (10) [1461, "Bro", "Jo", "01.08.2018", "abc", "USA", "USA", "MY COMPANY", "Catering", "A"]
...
length: 100
__proto__: Array(0)
head: Array(1)
0: (10) ["ID", "NAME", "FIRST NAME", "BIRTHDAY", "BIRTH PLACE", "BIRTH COUNTRY", "NATIONALITY", "ORGANISATION", "FUNCTION", "PLACE"]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

**EDIT3.:**

As Rob Newton suggested I edited the convert function like this:

```
public static native void exportCsvFromTable(JavaScriptObject originalData, String project, String name) /*-{
        var uri = 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;';

        function convertToCSV(jsData){
              //console.log(originalData);
              var json = jsData;
              //var fields = Object.keys(json);
              //var replacer = function(key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value }

              var headerCSV = json.head[0].join(',');

              var rowsCSV = json.data.map( function(row) {
                return row.join(',');
              } );

              rowsCSV.unshift(headerCSV);

              console.log(rowsCSV.join('\r\n'));

              return rowsCSV.join('\r\n');
            }

            var data = convertToCSV(originalData);
            //          window.location.href = uri + data;
            $entry(@com.mycompany.gxt.framework.view.dom.DOMUtils::downloadFile(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)("export.csv", uri, data));

}-*/;
```

The converted data looks okay:

```
ID,NAME,FIRST NAME,BIRTHDAY,BIRTH PLACE,BIRTH COUNTRY,NATIONALITY,ORGANISATION,FUNCTION,PLACE
31471,Test,Test,07.05.2019,New,,,XYZ,ikl,
31470,John,Doe,03.03.1988,,,Canada,XYZ,,
31469,New,Test,25.03.1999,Right,USA,USA,,LA
...
```

Sadly the download produces an invalid file with 0bytes :(

Comment: You are passing a string containing JSON text to exportCsvFromTable() and convertToCSV().  The function expects a javascript object.

Comment: I can help you if i would know what is `head` `cols`,`data`, showing a small sample of the data in that json object and what is the expected result will help a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying also myself to somehow log this out, but I don't know how to do that in this GWT... :(

Comment: Added the logged out JavaScriptObject!

Comment: And how should the CSV file look for that data?

Comment: as in the excel sheet. column header names are in “cols” and rows in the “data”. I don’t know why there is the head...

Comment: which browsers have you tested the download with?

Answer (score 0):

json data to csv in js

idon't know about GWT. may be it will help you

```
function convertToCSV(jsData){
      var json = jsData;
      var fields = Object.keys(json[0]);
      var replacer = function(key, value) { return value === null ? '' : value }
      var csv = json.map(function(row){
        return fields.map(function(fieldName){
          return JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)
        }).join(',')
      })
      csv.unshift(fields.join(',')) // add header column
      return csv.join('\r\n');
    }

function exportCSVFile(items, fileTitle) {
        var csv = convertToCSV(items);
        var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';
        var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
        } else {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            if (link.download !== undefined) {
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.setAttribute("href", url);
                link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
                link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I found this function already here on the site, my problem is with the integration with GWT :(

Comment: Well, I tried it and I see following error in my Javascript console: SEVERE: Exception caught: Exception caught: (TypeError) : json_0_g$.map is not a function com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: (TypeError) : json_0_g$.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a JavaScriptObject to your converter function, not a string containing JSON. Try the following changes to your code:

```
exportCsvFromTable(object.getJavaScriptObject(), GWT.getModuleName(), name);

public static native void exportCsvFromTable(JavaScriptObject originalData, String project, String name) /*-{
```

You show that your object has a property called `head` which is an array of length 1, and head[0] is an array of your header line column names.  So something like the following will give you your header line string:

```
var headerCSV = json.head[0].join(',');
```

The actual rows of data are in a property called `data` which is an array, and each item in the array is an array of the values in the row.

```
var rowsCSV = json.data.map( function(row) {
    return row.join(',');
  } );
```

Now join the header and rows, like:

```
rowsCSV.unshift(headerCSV) // add header column
return rowsCSV.join('\r\n');
```

Comment: Tried, this is what I see in the browser console: Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot convert undefined or null to object
 at Unknown.keys(Unknown@-1)
 at Unknown.convertToCSV_0_g$(as-0.js@30:238179)

Comment: Tried, now I get this: Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : json_0_g$.map is not a function
 at Unknown.convertToCSV_0_g$(zs-0.js@30:238185)
 at Unknown.exportCsvFromTable_1_g$(as-

Comment: I will add the logged out javascript object right now

Comment: the logged out JavaScriptObject is for me very strange... do you think the synthax is okay and can be parsed with this function? I see it uses {} and [] as well...

Comment: @VORIAND No I don't think the existing code will parse that object to give you a typical CSV format.  Refer to my update.

Comment: Looking good :) I logged out the created .csv, I think the format is okay and the download is starting, but the created file is 0bytes, so the download function is not okay yet... The downloadFile function is in my question, but will post the converting function as well right now.